# What type should an overload of the negation operator (!) have?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

If i overload the `!` operator in a class, what type should it return? In a book I found this (partial listing):

```
public class MyType {
    public int IntField { get; set; }

    public MyType(int intField) {
        IntField = intField;
    }

    public static bool operator !(MyType mt) {
        return (mt.IntField <= 0);
}
```

It does compile, but I would expect the `!` operator to return a `MyType` instance, something like

```
public static MyType operator !(MyType mt) {
    var result = new MyType(-mt.IntField);
    return result;
}
```

In fact, I would expect the compiler to demand that the `!` operator returns a `MyType`. But it doesn't.

So... why doesn't the return type of the `!` operator have to be the containing type? You **do** have to make the return type of `++` or `--` be the containing type.

Comment: That example is terrible. What book is this from?

Comment: I'd hate to discredit the author of the book, so I'm not gonna name the book. I *will* point the author to this question and its answers though.

Comment: If the author has published the book, he has to be ready to take criticism for ideas expressed in the book. And it's quite possible that this particular example is terrible and the rest of the book is good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose I asked you "what is the return type of concatenation"?  What would you say?  Probably you'd turn around and ask "concatenation of what?" Catenation is defined on chars, strings, sequences, catenable deques, languages, discrete finite automata and a thousand other things, so the type returned is determined by the type of the arguments. But typically the type of a concatenation is the type of the arguments. Not always; the concatenation of two chars is a string, for example. But typically.

Similarly, the question "what is the type of the ! operator?" depends entirely on what is being negated, and you haven't said what you are negating. Typically the negation of a T is another T, but it need not be.

I suspect you are not asking the right question. I think the question you ought to ask is "what is a realistic scenario in which you would overload the ! operator?" The example you give from the book is terrible; it does not motivate why the author of the code is overriding the operator at all.

Here's an more realistic example. Suppose we lived in a world without nullable types. You might decide to have three-valued logic:

```
sealed class MyBool
{
    private MyBool() {} // No one creates it!
    public static MyBool True = new MyBool();
    public static MyBool False = new MyBool();
    public static MyBool Unknown = new MyBool();
```

OK, what's the rule for negation of MyBool?  True becomes False, False becomes True, Unknown stays Unknown:

```
    public static MyBool operator !(MyBool b)
    { 
        if (b == True) return False;
        if (b == False) return True;
        return Unknown;
    }
```

In this scenario, the type of the ! operator is MyBool.

Of course, since C# 2.0 we have three-valued logic in the form of `Nullable<bool>`, but you might want more complex kinds of logic (or you might be writing C# 1.0 code).

It is harder to come up with reasonable examples of situations in which negation of a Foo results in a Bar; some sort of "monadic" workflow objects might be a possible situation -- where the negation of an object of a given type is an object of a different type that represents the deferred execution of the negation.

Comment: One example of `MyBool` found in the .Net Framework is [`SqlBoolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlboolean.aspx) .  See also [SqlBoolean.LogicalNot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlboolean.op_logicalnot.aspx), though the Return Value documentation seems a little off, in my opinion.

Comment: A non-contrived example where negation may yield different types is when representing logical expressions as types. So, for instance, applying negation (!) to a LogicalOr object may in fact return a LogicalNot.

Comment: @LBushkin: Indeed, I considered going there. If you create types like True and False and so on, you can actually build up systems where you force the compiler to solve little logic problems in order to type check the program. By constructing such a program you can show that analysis of C# programs is at least NP-HARD. I thought that might be a little esoteric for the purposes of this answer though.

Comment: Now I'm starting to wonder why you can't negate an `int`. I'd say the opposite of 5 is -5, so why can't you use `!5`?

Comment: Eric Lippert provides an example of forcing the compiler to solve logic problems [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/28/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-five.aspx).

Comment: @comecme: A lot of programmers coming from C++ would expect that `!5 == 0`.  Remember, `!` is called the [logical negation operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/f2kd6eb2.aspx)

Comment: @Brian: In C++, the the result `0` means `false`. So basically you're saying a lot of C++ programmers would expect the result to be boolean. I would expect `!(!i)` to be `i` again ([double negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation#Double_negation)).

Comment: @comecme: I'm confused.  If all you want is negation, couldn't you just use the `-` operator for that? For example, this is legal: `int x = 5; Trace.WriteLine(-x);`. Personally, I think the built in way of negating an `int` (i.e., using the [unary - operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wch5w409.aspx)) is much more intuitive.

Comment: @comecme: Historically in C there was no such thing as as a "boolean". There was only int! The convention in C was/is that a zero int is the same thing as "false" and a non-zero int is the same thing as "true". Moreover, ints can also be treated as arrays of bits. That's why there are three negation operators on ints in C.  ! does logical negation, treating ints as bools, ~ does bitwise negation, treating ints as bit arrays, and - does arithmetic negation, treating ints as numbers. If all this sounds horrid, that's because it is horrid. Ints are not bools.

Comment: @Brian: I don't want negation specifically, I was just wondering what type the `!` operator should return. Or, an example of when you would want to overload the `!` operator. Based on the answers I would say that all examples create some sort of a boolean, mostly a nullable one. As far as I'm concerned, it seems to me that most programmers will never actually use these overloads (on `!`, `true` and `false`).